# How to create a list of abbreviations in r-markdown for non-LaTeX output formats?

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I create a list of abbreviations in my r-markdown document if the output is non-LaTeX, MS word or HTML preferably?

I found a similar question on R-bloggers (https://www.r-bloggers.com/add-abbreviations-to-your-rmarkdown-doc/). Which is essentially supplying all your acronyms and their expansions as arguments and then arranging them into a data frame.

```
tribble(
    ~Abbreviation, ~ Explanation,
    "CIA", "Central Intelligence Agency",
    "dplyr", "data.frame plyr, a tool for working with data in a rectangular format",
    "ABC", "The first few letters of the alphabet"
) %>%
    arrange(Abbreviation)
```

But I am looking for a solution where, the entire document could be scanned and all explained acronyms could be generated as a list/dataframe.

Comment: Currently there is no tool for this, c.f. https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/199.

Comment: @RalfStubner I had checked this discussion when doing my own Google search. As this was posted in 2016, thought some new development might have happened. Thank you for the update!

Comment: pagedown has a basic support for lists of abbreviations, see https://pagedown.rbind.io/#list-of-abbreviations. I think a Pandoc filter could be developed for all output formats.