# Abbreviations/Acronyms for Quarto

Tags: rstudio, quarto

How can I create a list of abbreviations in my Quarto document if the output is non-LaTeX, MS word, or HTML, preferably?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Like, you want to show, say, `It's MS` when the document is rendered into `.docx` and `It's LaTeX` when rendered into `.tex`?

Comment: It seems to work on HTML formats like pagedown (see comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621138/how-to-create-a-list-of-abbreviations-in-r-markdown-for-non-latex-output-formats).)

Comment: So far it is not supported in pandoc, see also [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#extension-abbreviations). But I think it is solvable by writing your own [lua filter](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/filters.html).

Comment: Thank you, Julian. Do you have an example of how to add a filer like that?

Comment: You could take a look [here](https://rchaput.github.io/acronymsdown/) in the `inst` folder. There you find useful lua's for abbreviations.

Comment: Thank you. But if I enable the lua filter should be fine. How can I do that?

Comment: using `filters: [yourfilter.lua]`